# Can't exlude row in Twitter Dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, twitter

I'm analysing tweets with R. One of the Tweets in my Dataframe (consisting of 43305 observations) is causing problems in my analysis. With the search function I could find out that its row 15.

So my solution was:

```
mydataframe <- mydataframe[-15, ]
```

One observation disappeard but the tweet `nr.15` is still in my dataframe. 
Any solutions??

Comment: Please give a [mcve]!

Comment: That should have worked. Have you tried restarting R?